# Partial specialization with parameter pack behaves differently than manually expanded one

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, template-meta-programming, compiler-bug

I'm trying to understand why I'm getting different behavior with 2 templates that should be equivalent to me

Given

```
template<template<typename...> class TT, typename T1, typename T2>
class A {};
```

`is_a` is the generic version

```
template<typename T>
struct is_a : std::false_type
{
};

template<template<typename...> class TT, typename... T>
struct is_a<A<TT, T...>> : std::true_type
{
};
```

`is_a2` is the version which has been manually expanded to 2 types instead of a paramter pack

```
template<typename T>
struct is_a2 : std::false_type
{
};

template<template<typename...> class TT, typename T1, typename T2>
struct is_a2<A<TT, T1, T2>> : std::true_type
{
};
```

I would expect the 2 versions to behave identically when A is instantiated with 3 parameters, but this is not the case

See the code compiling https://wandbox.org/permlink/MjSwFLvWmH0n1QLk

I would expect `is_a` to work anywhere `is_a2` works.

Is this a compiler bug I should report?

**EDIT**

Apparently this works in clang https://wandbox.org/permlink/9n5pXUGtBa8cAvFw

Comment: You don't get this behavior [with clang](https://godbolt.org/z/AEW6Wr). I'd say that gcc has a bug here, but can't really say for sure.

Comment: Indeed clang works https://wandbox.org/permlink/9n5pXUGtBa8cAvFw . How can I make sure if it is a compiler bug on GCC side?

Comment: You can slightly modify your question to ask about that. I think that would be okay.

Comment: On MSVC it works too https://godbolt.org/z/Kkbv29. Also it will work on GCC if you change to `template<template<typename...> class TT, typename... T> A {};`.

Comment: Related: [core language issue 2328](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2328).

Comment: @Makers_F Report it as a bug to GCC. The developers can mark it "confirmed" if they agree that it's a bug, or explain to you why they think GCC is correct.

Comment: GCC bug reported: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=104305